# Worklight 6.0 Create View Patterns hangs loading pattern

Tags: design-patterns, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I just installed Worklight 6.0 Dev edition on eclipse Juno 64 bit.  When I open the mobile Navigation view and try to create a new Dojo Mobile View, where the Create view from UI pattern radio button is selected, the patterns are never displayed and an hourglass with the message *"Loading:"* is displayed.  This appears to hang.  I can click on Create empty view to create a view without patterns.  One more piece of information, I can see views if I run through the same scenario using the 32 bit version of eclipse.  Thanks for any help.

JT

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows? What Internet Explorer version you have installed in your system?

If you have Internet Explorer 8 or below, I think this won't work. If that's the case, try upgrading to Internet Explorer 9.